# How can you compare to what extent two lists are in the same order?

Tags: algorithm

I have two arrays containing the same elements, but in different orders, and I want to know the extent to which their orders differ.

The method I tried, didn't work. it was as follows:

For each list I built a matrix which recorded for each pair of elements whether they were above or below each other in the list. I then calculated a pearson correlation coefficient of these two matrices. This worked extremely badly. Here's a trivial example:

```
list 1:
1
2
3
4

list 2:
1
3
2
4
```

The method I described above produced matrices like this (where 1 means the row number is higher than the column, and 0 vice-versa):

```
list 1:
  1 2 3 4
1   1 1 1
2     1 1
3       1
4

list 2:
  1 2 3 4 
1   1 1 1
2     0 1 
3       1
4
```

Since the only difference is the order of elements 2 and 3, these should be deemed to be very similar. The Pearson Correlation Coefficient for those two matrices is 0, suggesting they are not correlated at all. I guess the problem is that what I'm looking for is not really a correlation coefficient, but some other kind of similarity measure. Edit distance, perhaps?

Can anyone suggest anything better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mean square of differences of indices of each element.

```
List 1: A B C D E
List 2: A D C B E
```

Indices of each element of List 1 in List 2 (zero based)

```
A B C D E
0 3 2 1 4
```

Indices of each element of List 1 in List 1 (zero based)

```
A B C D E
0 1 2 3 4
```

Differences:

```
A  B C D E
0 -2 0 2 0
```

Square of differences:

```
A B C D E
  4   4
```

Average differentness = 8 / 5.

Comment: How does this work when the arrays are (a,b,c,d,e) vs. (e,a,b,c,d)? The arrays differ only by a single rotation. But the above algorithm will give a difference of 4 ((16+1+1+1+1)/5). Is this what the OP intends?

Comment: That single rotation moved e to the opposite end of the list.  Seems like a reasonable measure to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, but is there any mileage in adapting a standard sort algorithm to count the number of swap operations needed to transform list1 into list2?

I think that defining the compare function may be difficult though (perhaps even just as difficult as the original problem!), and this may be inefficient.

edit: thinking about this a bit more, the compare function would essentially be defined by the target list itself. So for example if list 2 is:

1 4 6 5 3

...then the compare function should result in 1 < 4 < 6 < 5 < 3 (and return equality where entries are equal).

Then the swap function just needs to be extended to count the swap operations.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for the party here, but just for the record, I think Ben almost had it... if you'd looked further into correlation coefficients, I think you'd have found that **Spearman's rank correlation coefficient** might have been the way to go.

Interestingly, jamesh seems to have derived a similar measure, but not normalized.

See this [recent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859536/sorted-list-difference/859902#859902).

Comment: or better: See this page: [Wiki-Spearmans_rank_corr_coef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)

Comment: or check out this: [https://www.statology.org/spearman-correlation-python/](https://www.statology.org/spearman-correlation-python/)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider how many changes it takes to transform one string into another (which I guess it was you were getting at when you mentioned edit distance).

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Although I don't think l-distance takes into account rotation. If you allow rotation as an operation then:

1, 2, 3, 4

and

2, 3, 4, 1

Are pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a branch-and-bound algorithm that should work for any set of operators you like. It may not be real fast. The pseudocode goes something like this:

```
bool bounded_recursive_compare_routine(int* a, int* b, int level, int bound){
    if (level > bound) return false;
    // if at end of a and b, return true
    // apply rule 0, like no-change
    if (*a == *b){
        bounded_recursive_compare_routine(a+1, b+1, level+0, bound);
        // if it returns true, return true;
    }
    // if can apply rule 1, like rotation, to b, try that and recur
    bounded_recursive_compare_routine(a+1, b+1, level+cost_of_rotation, bound);
    // if it returns true, return true;
    ...
    return false;
}

int get_minimum_cost(int* a, int* b){
    int bound;
    for (bound=0; ; bound++){
        if (bounded_recursive_compare_routine(a, b, 0, bound)) break;
    }
    return bound;
}
```

The time it takes is roughly exponential in the answer, because it is dominated by the last bound that works.

Added: This can be extended to find the nearest-matching string stored in a trie. I did that years ago in a spelling-correction algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what formula it uses under the hood, but `difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio()` does exactly this:

```
ratio(self) method of difflib.SequenceMatcher instance:
    Return a measure of the sequences' similarity (float in [0,1]).
```

Code example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
sm = SequenceMatcher(None, '1234', '1324')
print sm.ratio()

>>> 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that is based on a little bit of [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Transpositions.2C_simple_transpositions.2C_inversions_and_sorting) is to count the number of *inversions* to convert one of the arrays into the other one. An *inversion* is the exchange of two neighboring array elements. In ruby it is done like this:

```
# extend class array by new method
class Array
  def dist(other)
    raise 'can calculate distance only to array with same length' if length != other.length
    # initialize count of inversions to 0
    count = 0
    # loop over all pairs of indices i, j with i<j
    length.times do |i|
      (i+1).upto(length) do |j|
        # increase count if i-th and j-th element have different order
        count += 1 if (self[i] <=> self[j]) != (other[i] <=> other[j])
      end
    end
    return count
  end
end
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
# try an example (prints 1)
puts l1.dist(l2)
```

The distance between two arrays of length n can be between 0 (they are the same) and n*(n+1)/2 (reversing the first array one gets the second). If you prefer to have distances always between 0 and 1 to be able to compare distances of pairs of arrays of different length, just divide by n*(n+1)/2.

A disadvantage of this algorithms is it running time of n^2. It also assumes that the arrays don't have double entries, but it could be adapted.

A remark about the code line "count += 1 if ...": the count is increased only if either the i-th element of the first list is *smaller* than its j-th element and the i-th element of the second list is *bigger* than its j-th element or vice versa (meaning that the i-th element of the first list is bigger than its j-th element and the i-th element of the second list is smaller than its j-th element). In short: (l1[i] < l1[j] and l2[i] > l2[j]) or (l1[i] > l1[j] and l2[i] < l2[j])

Answer (score 0):

If one has two orders one should look at two important ranking correlation coefficients:

1. Spearman's rank correlation coefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient 
   This is almost the same as Jamesh answer but scaled in the range -1 to 1.
   It is defined as:
   1 - ( 6 * sum_of_squared_distances ) / ( n_samples * (n_samples**2 - 1 )
2. Kendalls tau: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendalls_tau

When using python one could use:

```
 from scipy import stats

 order1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
 order2 = [ 1, 3, 2, 4]
 print stats.spearmanr(order1, order2)[0]
 >> 0.8000
 print stats.kendalltau(order1, order2)[0]
 >> 0.6667
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is using R language, I've implemented a function that computes the "spearman rank correlation coefficient" using the method described above by @bubake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859536/sorted-list-difference/859902#859902):

```
get_spearman_coef <- function(objectA, objectB) {
  #getting the spearman rho rank test 
  spearman_data <- data.frame(listA = objectA, listB = objectB)
  spearman_data$rankA <- 1:nrow(spearman_data) 
  rankB <- c()
  
  for (index_valueA in 1:nrow(spearman_data)) {
    for (index_valueB in 1:nrow(spearman_data)) {
      
      if (spearman_data$listA[index_valueA] == spearman_data$listB[index_valueB]) {
        rankB <- append(rankB, index_valueB)
      }
      
      
    }
  }
  spearman_data$rankB <- rankB
  spearman_data$distance <-(spearman_data$rankA - spearman_data$rankB)**2
  
  spearman <- 1 - ( (6 * sum(spearman_data$distance)) / (nrow(spearman_data) * ( nrow(spearman_data)**2 -1) ) )
  print(paste("spearman's rank correlation coefficient"))
  return( spearman)  
}
```

results :

> get_spearman_coef(c("a","b","c","d","e"), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
>
> > spearman's rank correlation coefficient: 1

> get_spearman_coef(c("a","b","c","d","e"), c("b","a","d","c","e"))
>
> > spearman's rank correlation coefficient: 0.9