# Sorted list difference

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, comparison

I have the following problem.

I have a set of elements that I can sort by a certain algorithm A . The sorting is good, but very expensive.

There is also an algorithm B that can approximate the result of A. It is much faster, but the ordering will not be exactly the same.

Taking the output of A as a 'golden standard' I need to get a meaningful estimate of the error resulting of the use of B on the same data.

Could anyone please suggest any resource I could look at to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

As requested : adding an example to illustrate the case : 
if the data are the first 10 letters  of the alphabet,

A outputs   : a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j

B outputs   : a,b,d,c,e,g,h,f,j,i

What are the possible measures of the resulting error, that would allow me to tune the internal parameters of algorithm B to get result closer to the output of A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Spearman's rho

I think what you want is [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient).  Using the index [rank] vectors for the two sortings (perfect `A` and approximate `B`), you calculate the rank correlation `rho` ranging from -1 (completely different) to 1 (exactly the same):

[image: Spearman's rho]

where d(i) are the difference in ranks for each character between A and B

You can defined your measure of error as a distance `D := (1-rho)/2`.

Comment: Yes This looks very much like the thing I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would determine the largest correctly ordered sub set.

```
                               +-------------> I
                               |   +--------->
                               |   |
A -> B -> D ----->  E  -> G -> H --|--> J
     |             ^ |             |    ^
     |             | |             |    |
     +------> C ---+ +-----------> F ---+
```

In your example 7 out of 10 so the algorithm scores 0.7. The other sets have the length 6. Correct ordering scores 1.0, reverse ordering 1/n.

I assume that this is related to the number of inversions. x + y indicates x <= y (correct order) and x - y indicates x > y (wrong order).

A + B + D - C + E + G + H - F + J - I

We obtain almost the same result - 6 of 9 are correct scorring 0.667. Again correct ordering scores 1.0 and reverse ordering 0.0 and this might be much easier to calculate.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for finding some algorithm that calculates the difference based on array sorted with A and array sorted with B as inputs?  Or are you looking for a generic method of determining on average how off an array would be when sorted with B?

If the first, then I suggest something as simple as the distance each item is from where it should be (an average would do better than a sum to remove length of array as an issue)

If the second, then I think I'd need to see more about these algorithms.

Comment: This isn't good enough, as if for example the the list is z, a, b, c, d… the whole list is shifted by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating [**RMS Error**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) may be one of the many possible methods. Here is small python code.

```
def calc_error(out_A,out_B):
        # in    <= input
        # out_A <= output of algorithm A
        # out_B <= output of algorithm B

        rms_error = 0

        for i in range(len(out_A)):
            # Take square of differences and add
            rms_error +=  (out_A[i]-out_B[i])**2 

        return rms_error**0.5   # Take square root

>>> calc_error([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6])
0.0
>>> calc_error([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,4,3,5,6]) # 4,3 swapped
1.414
>>> calc_error([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,4,6,3,5]) # 3,4,5,6 randomized
2.44
```

NOTE:
 Taking square root is not necessary but taking squares is as just differences may sum to zero. I think that calc_error function gives approximate number of wrongly placed pairs but I dont have any programming tools handy so :(.

Take a look at **[this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378204/how-can-you-compare-to-what-extent-two-lists-are-in-the-same-order)**

Comment: I was thinking about RMSE too. But the original question says "sorting is expensive", so I have to assume that the error metric must be calculated without ever having a canonical sorting to compare against. And without the canonical order, you can't compute RMSE.

Comment: No, the OP has access to the gold standard for training purposes.  He wants an error function so he can optimize his approximate sorter before turning it loose.

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to give a good generic answer, because the right solution for you will depend on your application.

One of my favorite options is just the number of in-order element pairs, divided by the total number of pairs. This is a nice, simple, easy-to-compute metric that just tells you how many mistakes there are. But it doesn't make any attempt to quantify the magnitude of those mistakes.

```
double sortQuality = 1;
if (array.length > 1) {
   int inOrderPairCount = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= array[i - 1]) ++inOrderPairCount;
   }
   sortQuality = (double) inOrderPairCount / (array.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something involving [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

Comment: I don't think Hamming distance is a good solution for this problem. It offers an element by element comparison but the distance between two elements does not say anything about sorting quality.

Comment: you are right, I did not say only using hamming distance, but just something that involves it.  If he wants to do a more expensive estimate, he should use distance calculations.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is using R language, I've implemented a function that computes the "spearman rank correlation coefficient" using the method described above by @bubake :

```
get_spearman_coef <- function(objectA, objectB) {
  #getting the spearman rho rank test 
  spearman_data <- data.frame(listA = objectA, listB = objectB)
  spearman_data$rankA <- 1:nrow(spearman_data) 
  rankB <- c()
  
  for (index_valueA in 1:nrow(spearman_data)) {
    for (index_valueB in 1:nrow(spearman_data)) {
      
      if (spearman_data$listA[index_valueA] == spearman_data$listB[index_valueB]) {
        rankB <- append(rankB, index_valueB)
      }
      
      
    }
  }
  spearman_data$rankB <- rankB
  spearman_data$distance <-(spearman_data$rankA - spearman_data$rankB)**2
  
  spearman <- 1 - ( (6 * sum(spearman_data$distance)) / (nrow(spearman_data) * ( nrow(spearman_data)**2 -1) ) )
  print(paste("spearman's rank correlation coefficient"))
  return( spearman)  
}
```

results :

> get_spearman_coef(c("a","b","c","d","e"), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
>
> > spearman's rank correlation coefficient: 1

> get_spearman_coef(c("a","b","c","d","e"), c("b","a","d","c","e"))
>
> > spearman's rank correlation coefficient: 0.9